# operator overloading in c++ ( with and without friend )

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, unary-operator

Hey, I would like to know the difference between these 2 operator definitions:

1:

```
class Rational{
//...
public:
//...
Rational operator -() const{ return Rational(-t,b);}
//...
};
```

2:

```
class Rational{
//...
public:
//...
friend Rational operator -(const Rational& v) {return Rational(-t,b);}
//...
};
```

as far as i understand, for the usage of:

```
Rational s = -r 

r.operator-()   // should happen
```

would like some explenation for the difference, thanks !

Comment: Are these declarations within the class?

Comment: Your #2 doesn't even need to be a friend - it doesn't access any private members of Rational. It can (and should) be declared/defined entirely outside of the class.

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, they are the same.

First of all, I don't think you have either written right.  They should be:

```
 // Member function.      "-r" calls r.operator-() 
 Rational Rational::operator -() const{ return Rational(-t,b);} 

 // (technically a) global function.   "-r"  calls ::operator-(r) 
 friend Rational operator -(const Rational& v) {return Rational(-v.t,v.b);}
```

The major difference is that if you have another type (say `MyRational`) which is convertible to a Rational object, then:

```
  MyRational mr = MyRational();
  Rational r = -mr;
```

will work with the second definition, but not for the first.